# Can't assign function to call or unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, operand

To take 1 away from the variable "glory", the variable needs to be an integer. When turning it into an integer I just receive: "Can't assign function to call".

```
import sys

glory = input("Glory charge: ")
glory_prev = glory
print(glory_prev)
pouch = 28
run_num = 0
nat_price = input("Nat price: ")

while True:
    run = input("You've done " + (str(run_num)) + " runs: ")
    if run == "a":
        (int(glory) -= 1
        pouch -= 1
        if glory == 0:
            print("New glory needed")
            glory = glory_prev
        if pouch == 0:
            print("Repair pouch")
            pouch = 28

    elif run == "q":
        sys.exit
    else:
        continue
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What would you expect `(int(glory) -= 1` to do?

Comment: Take 1 away from glory

Comment: `int(glory)` calls the function `int` with the argument `glory`.  It will probably return an integer.  Then you are trying to do something like `10 -= 1`, which doesn't make any sense

Comment: I don't really understand as I am quite new to python. surely that would just mean glory would then equal 9?

Comment: And also it is syntax error in python 3.5 that I'm using

Comment: @FynFTW how do you define `glory` initially?

Comment: I will just post my whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have to consider is to remove bracket before int of glory and change that glory syntax to

```
glory = int(glory) - 1
```

so the code will be like this

```
import sys

glory = input("Glory charge: ")
glory_prev = glory
print(glory_prev)
pouch = 28
run_num = 0
nat_price = input("Nat price: ")

while True:
    run = input("You've done " + (str(run_num)) + " runs: ")
    if run == "a":
        glory = glory - 1
        pouch -= 1
        if glory == 0:
            print("New glory needed")
            glory = glory_prev
        if pouch == 0:
            print("Repair pouch")
            pouch = 28

    elif run == "q":
        sys.exit
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: cant assign function to call because by that you were just giving function input in improper way. whenever you write a function on left hand side of = operator and assiging any valu to it , it will give this error like ex: a=3;int(a)=4;

Comment: While this is correct, it feels weird to me to have cast glory to an int in every iteration. Why not just do it once at the beginning?

Comment: haha by the way you need not to type cast also the input function of python takes input as a int only so glory itself is int so no need to typecast glory to int

Comment: input returns value as an int only you can see that by the following code

Comment: a = input()#input 3;type(a)#it will print int

Comment: well then wouldn't `glory -= 1` be enough instead of `glory = int(glory) - 1`?

Comment: yup but also no need to type cast at the beginning also i just edited FynFTW code nothing more

Comment: Yeah I don't use `input()` much and since you guys were casting I expected it was returning a string